# Manually registering other microservices in Eureka from a Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I'd like to build a Spring Boot application to register several microservices with Eureka, so my app would act as an external register. I can find tons of examples about self-registration (with `application.yml` config + `@EnableEurekaClient`) but nothing specifically about 3rd party registration and spring boot. I'm wondering if I could use `@EnableEurekaClient` and `eureka.client.registerWithEureka=false` and then injecting some spring bean to access Eureka Registry (maybe an instance of `org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry`).

Any help with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't have any examples but there is a service registry interface that the class you mentioned uses. The trouble is that eureka requires a heartbeat and unless you do that manually as well, your registrations won't stay in eureka as it won't receive the heartbeats it requires